# Split a <td> table element into LEFT and RIGHT justified

Tags: html, css, html-table

Whats the best way to split up a table element `<td>`?  I don't really want to use nested tables. I need the internal element to have two elements one that is left justified and the other to be right justified with no border.

For example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>LEFT, RIGHT</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

any other ways to do this besides the following?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>LEFT</td>
<td>RIGHT</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want the internal element to be a `<span>` or whatever is best for this.

Comment: have you tried two `span`'s or two `divs`'s

Comment: Couldn't agree with Michael more, spans and divs are the way to go when doing fancy positioning.

Comment: I eventually implemented this with two <span> blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="float:left">LEFT</div><div style="float:right">RIGHT</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not a good thing to do.  One should not embed style data into the HTML; that is pretty much deprecated at this point.

Comment: Embedding styles is still necessary when working with emails because most clients strip out the `<head>` and `<style>` tags

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
<td><div class="left>LEFT</div><div class="right">RIGHT</div></td>
```

then my css would resemble:

```
td{position: relative;}
td .left{position: absolute; text-align: left; left: 0;}
td .right{position: absolute; text-align: right; right: 0;}
```

... or something along those lines.

Comment: Is it better to use <span> I dont want any newlines.

Comment: Newlines are not inherent to divs, especially when you're using absolute positioning.  You shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: This worked for me, but I found I had to have `top:0` in both `.left` and `.right` otherwise the vertical position was out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, although spans and divs are much better imo.

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr width="100%">
  <td width="100%">
   <span style="float:left;">left</span>
   <span style="float:right;">right</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The floats didn't seem to look right so I used flexbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/6rc8w709/

```
.td-content{
  display:flex;
}
.child{
  flex:1;
}
.right{
  text-align:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="td-content">
        <div class="child">
          LEFT
        </div>
        <div class="child right">
          RIGHT
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is the right approach since it is now supported by all major browsers. This is an alternative approach if you need to target an older browsers or you don't like the drawbacks of floats. With this approach you can control the overflow of the left and right segment better and you can easily add a centered segment if you need one.

CSS:

```
table{
  width: 100%;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.cell{
  display: table-cell;
}

.cell .left{
  text-align: left;
}

.cell.right{
  text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <span class="cell left">LEFT</span>
        <span class="cell right">RIGHT</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```